# Replace div's content after submission

Tags: php

I went through several posts but I am not able to find an answer for what I'm trying to do. If I missed something pls point me to the post.

I have a form that appears in small box. What I want to happen is to instead of redirecting the visitor to a different page in order to see the 'Thank you' message to keep him to the same page and change the content of the div.

I have managed to go half way there (thanks to a post found here).

I am able to not redirect the visitor plus show him a 'Thank You' message, but I am not able to refresh the content. I still see the form.

I'm only familiar with html, css and a bit php so if there's a solution that doesn't include jquery, etc. would be great.

Here's what I have so far:

HTML

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">  
                    <form action="" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" novalidate>
                    <div class="mc-field-group">
                    <input id="firstname3" type="text" value="" name="FNAME" placeholder="'Ονομα">
                    </div>

                    <div class="mc-field-group">
                    <input id="primaryemail3" type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>

                    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                    <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                    <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                    </div> 

                    <div class="myResultDiv">

                    <input name="subscribe" class="button_link hover_fade large_button red button_widget" type="submit" value="ΣΤΕΙΛΤΕ ΤΟ ΔΩΡΟ ΜΟΥ!"></div>
                    </form>

                    <?php if (isset($_POST['subscribe'])) : ?>
                    <p>Thank you for subscribing!</p>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <p class="under_button2"></p>

                    <div class="af-clear">
                    </div>

                    </div>
                    </div>                  
                    <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Comment: You may not be familiar with it, but your going to need to use javascript in order to do this. There is no way for PHP to manipulate a document already sent to the browser.

Comment: Hi MrGlass! That's what my research came down to. Just wanted to make sure that there isn't another way. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I took the question to mean that you were looking for the old fashioned, submit the form -> rebuild the page, type solution.  From your code and question.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I (along with most of the other people) misunderstood the question. It is considered bad practice to do what you are suggesting. If the user reloads, they will resubmit the form and their entry will be processed twice. It is highly recommended to redirect the user to a different page on a successful form submission, in order to avoid this.

Comment: Please add the URL of any related posts in your question, it helps to provide background.

Comment: @MrGlass I follow that rule with all my forms. That's a special occasion that need that to be done in order to not disorient the client.

Comment: @Jack I'm sorry I thought I had added one. Here's a [link] http://topgreekgyms.fitnessforum.gr/deals
I'm referring to the box at the top right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your conditional logic outside the `div`  like...

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['subscribe'])) { ?>
    <p>Thank you for subscribing!</p>
<?php }else{ ?>

   ---- FORM DIV HERE ----
<?php } ?>
```

This is under the assumption that you are looking for a server-side solution.  i.e. you submit the form and rebuild the page.

Comment: Hey there! It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: oops sorry, I changed the last php tag now.  It had `endif` instead of closing the braces.  I had copied it from your question and then changed the logic and forgot that part.

Comment: I guess I'm doing something wrong cause I cannot manage to make it work.
You can see the whole code above, so what I'm doing is the following:

` "...<input name="subscribe" class="button_link hover_fade large_button red button_widget" type="submit" value="ΣΤΕΙΛΤΕ ΤΟ ΔΩΡΟ ΜΟΥ!"></div>
     
     <?php if (isset($_POST['subscribe'])) { ?>
     <p>Thank you for subscribing!</p>
     <?php }else{ ?>
          
     </form>

     </div>
     
     <?php } ?>" `
Is that correct?

Comment: The action attribute is empty.

Comment: @kat_indo no that is not correct.  in my example where I put `--- FORM DIV HERE ---` put the whole code for the form in that area.  The entire div.  That way if the form has not been submitted, it will show, if it has it will not.

Comment: You're right!
I guess my brain was completely off yesterday. That exactly what I was trying to achieve.
I came across something new though. Is there a way to get back the form after refreshing the page? Right now it's stuck to 'Thank you for subscribing message'

Answer (score 1):

@kat_indo for change the text content of a div

```
 document.getElementById("yourDivId").innerText = "New text Content";
```

Comment: it would be really great if you could provide me some more details on where I'm suppose to use that code.

Comment: Sorry I see now I misunderstood your question, I think you need to change the text content of a div but instead you need to reuse a PHP page. The right answer is below from @NappingRabbit.

Comment: @kat_indo  yeh the title threw me too, almost all of my forms are processed with `ajax` now days.  The title `change contents of div` made me jump to that too.

Comment: Ok! So, how do I fix that?